# Sci-fi book involving an EMP event with man in Alaska with his family back in the lower 48

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book on Kindle Unlimited a year or two ago. An electromagnetic pulse event hits while a man is on a business trip in Alaska and his family (a wife and  3 girls, I think) are back home in the lower 48 states. The family is well prepared for such an event with guns and supplies. The story follows the man trying to get home while his family copes with deteriorating conditions in their suburban neighborhood. The man's journey includes travel on a boat to one of the Aleutian Islands. I believe the book ends with the family deciding to leave for a  cabin they have somewhere. There were sequels intended.

Comment: lol. The same story with a female protagonist; https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28803924-dark-new-world

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly [***Enduring the Crisis***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01K1FBUOS) by K.D. Kinney

> The Powell Family has been preparing for a disaster for years. However, timing is everything. When an EMP nuclear event takes out the grid and brings the nation to a complete stop, Tammy and Ben may not have been as prepared as they thought.
>
> Tammy is a food storage and emergency preparedness specialist. So she thinks. She and her five daughters will find out how prepared they are when they're put through the ultimate test when the worst happens. Having everything she needs won't bring all her family members home or keep the crazies away. What's worse is she has no way to contact her husband Ben to find out if he survived.
>
> **Ben is supervising a road-building project in a remote fishing village in Alaska when the state's defense system takes out what could have been a nuclear EMP disaster.** The lights are still on where he is, but with all flights grounded, there's no easy way back to Anchorage, much less the lower forty-eight. He might be thousands of miles away from the disaster but he's determined to return home to his family no matter what it takes.
>
> As North America is in chaos, Tammy and Ben know the hardships that are in store for them and their family. However, nothing could have prepared them for the real struggles they encounter as they try to protect and reunite with the ones they love.

[image]

> Sequels were indicated. By the end of the book, Ben is in Kodiak and Tammy, while slightly injured is, indeed, planning on leaving the suburbs.

Comment: lol. Are these all being written by the same author?

Answer (score 3):

Could this be The [Journey Home: An EMP Survival Story](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Journey-Home-Survival-Story-Aftermath-ebook/dp/B01MT83KG6)?

> This is the story of the Miller family, Jack, Amy, and their sons
>   Kenny and Danny. Separated by half a continent after an EMP attack
>   sends the United States back to the Stone Age, the Millers are
>   desperate to reunite as they struggle to survive.
>
> Jack Miller isn’t too worried about the apocalypse. He has been
>   prepping for a few years and has a basement stocked with the food and
>   supplies his family needs to ride out a disaster. Today though, he is
>   out of town on a business trip. An EMP strike delivered by a rogue
>   nation leaves him stranded over a thousand miles away from his home.
>   This is the last place he expected to be during a disaster. He sets
>   out on an epic journey home armed only with his know how and survival
>   skills. What he encounters leaves him questioning how prepared any
>   lone man can be.

[image]

Comment: No, I'm afraid it's not this one. No adventures in Alaskan waters here. There are so many books in this genre with similar plots that it makes it hard to track down.