# EMP Kindle ebook series where the prepared dad is home alone while his family are scattered far away

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic

I read an ebook that was the first of a series, but I can't remember the author or title. This story is different from others I've read, in that the prepper father is home  and his daughter and wife are each in different locations far from home.

Browser searches return too many results to whittle down with filters. It is not a *McClane Apocalypse* story.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be *[Enduring the Crisis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01K1FBUOS)* by K.D. Kinney as per [Sci-fi book involving an EMP event with man in Alaska with his family back in the lower 48](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194039/sci-fi-book-involving-an-emp-event-with-man-in-alaska-with-his-family-back-in-th)?

> The Powell Family has been preparing for a disaster for years. However, timing is everything. When an EMP nuclear event takes out the grid and brings the nation to a complete stop, Tammy and Ben may not have been as prepared as they thought.
>
> Tammy is a food storage and emergency preparedness specialist. So she thinks. She and her five daughters will find out how prepared they are when they're put through the ultimate test when the worst happens. Having everything she needs won't bring all her family members home or keep the crazies away. What's worse is she has no way to contact her husband Ben to find out if he survived.
>
> **Ben is supervising a road-building project in a remote fishing village in Alaska when the state's defense system takes out what could have been a nuclear EMP disaster.** The lights are still on where he is, but with all flights grounded, there's no easy way back to Anchorage, much less the lower forty-eight. He might be thousands of miles away from the disaster but he's determined to return home to his family no matter what it takes.
>
> As North America is in chaos, Tammy and Ben know the hardships that are in store for them and their family. However, nothing could have prepared them for the real struggles they encounter as they try to protect and reunite with the ones they love.

Comment: If this is the answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.